# How to display video as icons in website?

Tags: asp.net, html, video

Is there a way to display the video in a website page as an arranges icons of videos or thumbnails, so whenever I click on one video it should open a new window to play that video? not play it in the same page.

as this code, but the target="_blank" not leading me to another page?

```
<a href="video1.aspx" target="_blank">
        <object type="video/x-ms-wmv" data="Videos/clock.avi" width="320" height="255" >
            <param name="src" value="Videos/clock.avi">
            <param name="autoStart" value="0">
            alt : <a href="Videos/clock.avi">clock.avi</a>
        </object>
    </a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you see that with Youtube or other streaming website, is not VideoObject was open a website with video, is just a link to one page with the same video...

You have lot of method for create this "effect" , for optimize, you want just load One image (for create a thumbnails) of your video for create the link

```
<a href="pageofyourvideo.aspx" target="_blank">
    <img src="yourVideoImage.jpg" title="myVideotitle" />
</a>
```

because, it's unnecessary to load your video, if it's just for link here in other page...

In your video Page, you can juste play your video...

```
<div id="myVideoBox">
    <object type="video/x-ms-wmv" data="Videos/clock.avi" width="320" height="255" >
        <param name="src" value="Videos/clock.avi">
        <param name="autoStart" value="0">
    </object>
</div>
```

If you've few competences in your language ( aspx, html ? ) you want to create one same page for all your videos, with a parameter in your  link in all thumbnails...

For sample, you can create two thumbnails with the same link, and just parameter change :

sample with php link :

```
<!-- first Thumbnails link to video1.avi -->
<a href="pageofyourvideo.php?myvideo=video1.avi" target="_blank">
    <img src="yourVideoImage.jpg" title="myVideotitle" />
</a>

<!-- second thumbnails link to video2.avi -->
<a href="pageofyourvideo.php?myvideo=video2.avi" target="_blank">
    <img src="yourVideoImage2.jpg" title="myVideotitle2" />
</a>
```

and you received parameters in your video page : (always with php...)

```
<!-- If parameter "myvideo" was "video2.avi" video2.avi was played... --> 
<div id="myVideoBox">
    <object type="video/x-ms-wmv" data="Videos/clock.avi" width="320" height="255" >
        <param name="src" value="<?php echo $_GET["myvideo"]; ?>">
        <param name="autoStart" value="0">
    </object>
</div>
```

I use .php for sample because I'm not familiar with .aspx but you can make this sample in .aspx :-)